# Why does restarting unity close all (or most) of my apps?

Tags: 16.04, unity

Today Unity bugged out on me (the volume button on the top right wasn't reacting to clicks). I figured I'd restart unity to fix it, so I pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and entered `unity`. This did restart Unity (and fixed my problem) but also closed all (or maybe most, not sure) of my apps, e.g., Chrome and Kate.

Why does this happen? Can I fix such problems as the volume one without closing all my apps?

Answer (score 0):

Of Course! First of all install ***gksu*** (You can install it by typing:
***sudo apt install gksu***)
  then press **ALT + F2**  and type: **unity --replace** and unity will retsart/refresh with out closing any open windows.
another way is to hit **CTRL + ALT F9** then hit **CTRL ALT F7**
Hope this helps!

Comment: `unity --replace` got my chrome killed too. Synaptic and Nautilus were not killed.

Comment: opps sorry forgot to mention that it might close chrome and/or chromium

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. About the ctrl+alt+f... stuff - it didn't restart unity. And I don't think it's supposed to - I've always used these key combos to just switch between virtual displays, which is not supposed to *do* anything to those displays, like restart unity on them.

Comment: somhow it works with my machine. every time a mess up somthing with unity i use themm and its all refreshed i guess thought it would work.

Comment: Just a note: According to `man unity`, `unity --replace` does exactly the same as just `unity` (which is what I was already using, as noted in my question). The `--replace` option is a no-op. Also, I don't think the things listed in your answer require installing `gksu`.